# SAS output through verbatim in beamer

Tags: beamer, verbatim

I've tough time to manage SAS output through verbatim in beamer. Could someone help in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: More appropriate for tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Header}
\begin{verbatim}
SAS OUTPUT
\end{verbatim}
\end{frame}
```

It will break without the `fragile` argument.

Comment: Thanks Dr. Hyndman for your reply. The SAS output is not formating correctly. Below is the LaTeX code that I'm using. Please give me any advise. Thanks                                                   \begin{frame}[fragile] 
\frametitle{Multiple Mean Comparisons}
\begin{verbatim}                      
                                                 Sum of          Source                      DF         Squares     Mean Square    F Value    Pr > F
         Model                        3     1080.000000      360.000000       3.56    0.0382
\end{verbatim}
\end{frame}

Comment: NB! it also breaks if you add a comment `\end{frame}%Header` for example!